# Avoid using $timeout in Angular UI Modal

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/7fiRhSP3JKUcXSWC2z1w?p=preview) I have an Angular UI Modal wrapped in a directive. From the controller, I call a method to open the modal, but to do so I need to use `$timeout`, otherwise, the DOM hasn't finished rendering the directive.

This seems to work, however, what would happen if whatever needs to be completed hasn't finished after the `$timeout` expires? The `$timeout` may work in a development environment but may fail in production. Is it a bad practice to use `$timeout`? How to avoid using it in this example?

HTML

```
<div modal control="modalCtl"></div>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('myCtl', function($scope,$timeout) {
    $scope.modalCtl = {};       
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.modalCtl.openModal();
    },100);         
})
.directive('modal', function ($uibModal) {
    var directive = {};
    directive.restrict = 'EA';
    directive.scope = {    
        control: '='
    };
    directive.link = function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.control = scope.control || {};            
        scope.control.openModal = function() {
            scope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                template: '<button ng-click="close()">Close</button>',
                scope: scope
            })
        };
        scope.close = function () {
            scope.modalInstance.close();
        };
    };
    return directive;
});
```

Comment: you should be ok with the timeout. I would decrease the time to 0, tho, since timeout will send your call to the bottom of the event loop. For best practice, I would create an init function in your controller where you can place your timeout (which would be better wrapped within it's own descriptive function)

Comment: I generally use service instead of directive in such a case. Your directive only job is calling $uibModal service and this is not a suitable job for directive. If you want to proxy just use service not directive...

Comment: @EduardoLaHozMiranda Can you give an example of the init function?

Comment: in the bottom of your ctrl you would write:

function init () { //call function that starts timeout here }

and then at the very last line of your ctrl just trigger init();

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To avoid using `$timeout` the directive can notify controller when everything is ready. Take a look:

```
.directive('modal', function ($uibModal) {      
    var directive = {};    
    directive.restrict = 'EA';    
    directive.scope = {    
            control: '=',
            onReady: '&'  // <-- bind `onReady` with  `onModalReady`            
        };

    directive.link = function (scope, element, attrs) {

      scope.control = scope.control || {};

      scope.control.openModal = function() {
          scope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
              template: '<button ng-click="close()">Close</button>',
              scope: scope
            })                
        };

        scope.close = function () {
            scope.modalInstance.close();
        };

      scope.onReady(); // <-- notify controller
    };    
    return directive;    
});
```

Out HTML:

```
 <div modal on-ready="onModalReady()" control="modalCtl"></div>
```

Our controller:

```
 $scope.onModalReady = function(){
   $scope.modalCtl.openModal();
 }
```

<kbd>[Changed Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/d0tGJ8yh1PLmKD2WEfsN?p=preview)</kbd>

---

About comment `@Eduardo La Hoz Miranda`

> you should be ok with the timeout. I would decrease the time to 0, tho, since timeout will send your call to the bottom of the event loop.

Generally when we initialize `$timeout` with 0 milliseconds or with no argument as:

```
 $timeout(function(){
   $scope.modalCtl.openModal();
 });
```

We delay `$scope.modalCtl.openModal()` to run before **next** digest cycle a.e. last in queue. So in this case directive link will run 1st from beginning to to the end and only after you will enter to `$timeout`.

> The $timeout may work in a development environment but may fail in production.

On Production you have the same code. It should work. I believe the problem is in something else. If you are not confident with `$timeout` use above mentioned way I posted.

<kbd>[Your Logged Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hrToQgLyCuuzki4leAM7?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: when you call `scope.onReady();` why does that mean that the directive is ready? how do you know that the DOM was already loaded?

Comment: @ps0604 `link` function, a.e.  `postLink`, runs after the template is put in. So you fine here.

Comment: worked for me. What if I have another complex object (such a jQuery object wrapped in a directive) in the modal itself? should I chain the `onReady` calls?

Comment: @ps0604 jQuery has its own callbacks when element is ready. Keep in mind, since jQuery is 3d party, to notify Angular we should wrap   `scope.onReady();` with `$timeout` 0 ms or `$apply` to trigger digest cycle.

Comment: sorry but this code looks awful, such interactions are bad. http://plnkr.co/edit/uBsosFwA95vUesjcxrtp?p=preview

Comment: @PetrAveryanov well, I agree that I would write it by diff. way. However keep in mind we don't know all his code and demo he posted is only simplified code snippet that shows the problem.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov I need to open and close the modal several times from the controller, how will you do that in your example?

Comment: then you add param like 'openTrigger' to directive, $watch it and open modal if changes. Reason why adding link from parent controller to child controller is that it is hard to maintant it. (I.e. if child is destroyed - it should be removed, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

When link function of directive is finished, it can emit a message that it's ready.

And controller listens to this message and displays modal when received.

Code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('myCtl', function($scope,$timeout) {
  $scope.modalCtl = {};
    $scope.$on("hey", function() {
    $scope.modalCtl.openModal();
  });
})
.directive('modal', function ($uibModal) {

  var directive = {};

  directive.restrict = 'EA';

  directive.scope = {    
    control: '='
  };

  directive.link = function (scope, element, attrs) {

  scope.control = scope.control || {};

  scope.control.openModal = function() {
    scope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      template: '<button ng-click="close()">Close</button>',
      scope: scope
  })

  };

  scope.close = function () {
        scope.modalInstance.close();
  };

  scope.$emit("hey");
};

return directive;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using timeout for any arbitrary waits on code executing is generally bad.  As you state in your question, depending on the overall context of the page you are loading, you have no guarantee that the directive will be ready at the time your controller runs.

It seems like you have too many levels of abstraction here.  Something is rendering a div that when it is fully rendered, shows a modal.

Wouldn't it make more sense to just have the thing that is rendering the div create and show the modal instead ?

Comment: The problem is that I cannot tell when a directive finished loading; for example if the directive wraps a JQuery object the DOM is available only after $timeout.